# copy questions from superuser?

Tags: discussion, migration

Hello,

Previously I asked unix questions on superuser, can I copy them here together with the answers?

Answer (score 9):

We (well, Andrew Stacey) came up with these guidelines on the [tex SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/importing-questions-from-so/47#47) that I think make sense:

1. Only ask the question if when reading it you think, "Hmm, I'd like to know the answer to that one too.".
2. Only ask the question if it hasn't been satisfactorily answered.
3. Re-ask the question rather than just cut-and-pasting it.
4. Link back to the original question.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's fine to copy content. Instead of copying, perhaps we should migrate questions frmo there to here. However, I don't know how to move questions, comments *and* answers from there to here.

I copied a question from [superuser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148/colorizing-your-terminal-and-shell-environment) to here. Why?

- I only got a single response (besides myself) at SU, after several weeks, even after setting a bounty. On Un*x.stackexchange, I got 4 responses in one day. I can come up with several theories for why the response rate is better here, but overall I believe that SU might be inadequate for Unix questions, or it's mission is too broad, or something else.
- These sites are an experiment. Perhaps this site will provide better content then SU.
- Un*x.stackexchange needs to be populated with content and good questions. When someone Googles for a question, they should end up here. We make good content, and the SE sites are ranked highly by Google and Bing.
- I don't care much about redundancy, but again perhaps we should migrate questions from SU to here to avoid redundancy. This site doesn't overlap with SU or SF. It's more like SF and SU overlap with this site ;)

Comment: I asked this question on [meta.stackoverflow jeff atwood said that the migration path wouldn't be defined until the sites were out of beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60407/can-so-sf-su-questions-be-migrated-to-beta-sites).

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, those question shouldn't be copied to unix.stackexchange purposely, so redundancy can be avoided.

OTH, if someone, duplicates questions from superuser, they shouldn't be downvoted but the answer should include a link to superuser post.